# Does any current SegWit or blocksize increase proposal also seek an increase in the OP_RETURN byte limit?

Tags: block-size-increase, op-return, segregated-witness

Does any current SegWit or blocksize increase proposal also seek an increase in the OP_RETURN byte limit?

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_RETURN

Are there any current pull requests that seek an increase in the current 80 byte limit?

If the current OP_RETURN byte limit is 80, why does the StackExchange "op-return" tag still reference a 40 byte limit?

"An opcode that allows you to create an unspendable transaction output that stores up to 40 bytes of data."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there are no BIPS (Bitcoin Improvement Proposals) that seek to increase the 80 byte limit as you can see [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips).

Doing a cursory [search on that repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=OP_RETURN), you can see that only a few mention OP_RETURN at all.